# I'm using node/webpack with Wordpress

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, webpack

......and I've no idea what the hell I'm doing.

Okay let me explain I'm going back over a Wordpress course I did on Udemy where the now AWOL instructor implemented a automated workflow for us to use whereby anytime we typed PHP or JS the webpage would reload automatically, and it's working, actually it's working too fast for me. This time round for some reason it's driving me bonkers cos when I'm writing my code the page is recompiled before I can even finish typing a complete line of code! The webpage generates a parse error and I have to manually refresh the page when I'm done to clear the error as it doesn't get automatically refreshed due to the error, which sort of defeats the purpose of the automation.

The automated workflow was basically implemented by doing the following:

- I've installed 2 files package.json & webpack.config.js into my theme
  folder
- Then I ran `npm run devFast`
- Then by changing functions.php we got the WP theme to use the Node
  generated assets. Node serves up all of the JavaScript and CSS within
  one single bundled file, bundled.js

I've no idea where to start in asking for help with this so thought I'd start here. As I say any help with this would be appreciated even if you just signpost me. I'm also using Local by Flywheel to host the site locally and this has been a great tool.

If it helps my webpack file is ...

```
/*
  SUPER IMPORTANT: This config assumes your theme folder is named
  exactly 'fictional-university-theme' and that you have a folder
  inside it named 'bundled-assets' - If you'd like to adapt this
  config to work with your own custom folder structure and names
  be sure to adjust the publicPath value on line #116. You do NOT
  need to update any of the other publicPath settings in this file,
  only the one on line #116.
*/

const currentTask = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event
const path = require("path")
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const ManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin")
const fse = require("fs-extra")

const postCSSPlugins = [require("postcss-import"), require("postcss-mixins"), require("postcss-simple-vars"), require("postcss-nested"), require("postcss-hexrgba"), require("postcss-color-function"), require("autoprefixer")]

class RunAfterCompile {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap("Update functions.php", function () {
      // update functions php here
      const manifest = fse.readJsonSync("./bundled-assets/manifest.json")

      fse.readFile("./functions.php", "utf8", function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }

        const scriptsRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/scripts.+?'", "g")
        const vendorsRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/vendors.+?'", "g")
        const cssRegEx = new RegExp("/bundled-assets/styles.+?'", "g")

        let result = data.replace(scriptsRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["scripts.js"]}'`).replace(vendorsRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["vendors~scripts.js"]}'`).replace(cssRegEx, `/bundled-assets/${manifest["scripts.css"]}'`)

        fse.writeFile("./functions.php", result, "utf8", function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err)
        })
      })
    })
  }
}

let cssConfig = {
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: ["css-loader?url=false", { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: postCSSPlugins } }]
}

let config = {
  entry: {
    scripts: "./js/scripts.js"
  },
  plugins: [],
  module: {
    rules: [
      cssConfig,
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", ["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "12" } }]]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

if (currentTask == "devFast") {
  config.devtool = "source-map"
  cssConfig.use.unshift("style-loader")
  config.output = {
    filename: "bundled.js",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/"
  }
  config.devServer = {
    before: function (app, server) {
      /*
        If you want the browser to also perform a traditional refresh
        after a save to a JS file you can modify the line directly
        below this comment to look like this instead. I'm using this approach
        instead of just disabling Hot Module Replacement beacuse this way our
        CSS updates can still happen immediately without a page refresh.

        If you're using a slower computer and the new bundle is not ready
        by the time this is reloading the browser you can always just set the 
        "hot" property a few lines below this to false instead of true. That
        will work on all computers and the only trade off is the browser will
        perform a traditional refresh even for CSS changes as well.
        */

      // server._watch(["./**/*.php", "./**/*.js"])
      server._watch(["./**/*.php", "!./functions.php"])
    },
    public: "http://localhost:3000",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    disableHostCheck: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname),
    contentBasePublicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
  }
  config.mode = "development"
}

if (currentTask == "build" || currentTask == "buildWatch") {
  cssConfig.use.unshift(MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader)
  postCSSPlugins.push(require("cssnano"))
  config.output = {
    publicPath: "/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/bundled-assets/",
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "bundled-assets")
  }
  config.mode = "production"
  config.optimization = {
    splitChunks: { chunks: "all" }
  }
  config.plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "styles.[chunkhash].css" }), new ManifestPlugin({ publicPath: "" }), new RunAfterCompile())
}

module.exports = config
```

Comment: I should have said I'm using the auto-save feature in VS Code and to save my sanity I've turned this off which is doing the job. But is there another or better way?

Comment: Why dont you use a text editor and copy paste your changes so that way you can update when ready? You can also look if there are other npm commands such as npm run dev.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. VS Code would auto save and thus force the refresh, because you are writing in functions.php. Turning off auto-save is the answer.

Comment: I guess I was wondering if there was a setting in the webpack cfg file I could fine tune but you are right I should just stick with turning off auto save in VSCode. It's a case of KISS!

Answer (score 0):

As already posted:

I should have said I'm using the auto-save feature in VS Code and to save my sanity I've turned this off which is doing the job. But is there another or better way?